# Java Applet connecting to a wrong address

Tags: java, tomcat, applet

I have a web application consisting of a simple html page and an applet running on Tomcat 6.
The structure of the application follows:

```
tomcat\webapps\_salome_trs
\saloment_trs\plugin\myapplication (the folder plug-in has other subdirectories for other applcations)  
\myapplication\lib\mylib.jar
the applet is in
tomcat\webapps\_salome_trs\myapplet.jar
```

When I execute the applet from the webpage, it tries to connect to _salome_trs\classOne.class
classOne is in mylib.jar, but unfortunately the webserver doesn't load this class in _salome_trs
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When you created the jar what did you specify as your manifest start class?.I don't know if you dont specify a start class then it picks one by default.A good easy to use program is JarMaker instead of using command line